# How to get a reference to elemental.html.FormData

Tags: gwt, gwt-elemental

I'm sure this is a simple problem... I am trying to use elementals FormData in gwt.

How do I get a reference to it? There is a JsFormData

```
public class JsFormData extends JsElementalMixinBase  implements FormData {
  protected JsFormData() {}

  public final native void append(String name, String value, String filename) /*-{
    this.append(name, value, filename);
  }-*/;
}
```

But this has a protected constructor... and I can't find any other reference to FormData...

Do I need to subclass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public final native static JsFormData newJsFormData() /*-{
    return new $wnd.FormData();
}-*/;
```

and then you can simply call it

```
JsFormData formData = newJsFormData();
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I realised that because it's a javascript object it can only be instantiated in java script...